# Test-Path returns True but ExtractToDirectory Could not find path

Tags: powershell, zip

I have a simple powershell script which is supposed to ease some deployment tasks.

In an earlier portion of the script, I create a virtual drive mapped to Z: which is on a  remote server. The part that is tripping up is when it tries to unzip the files on the remote server mapped to Z:

```
function UnzipBuild($destinationFolder)
{    

    Add-Type -assembly "System.IO.Compression.Filesystem"    
    $zipFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationFolder -Filter *.zip
    foreach($zip in $zipFiles)
    {
        $folderName = $zip.ToString().TrimEnd(".zip")
        $extractPath = Join-Path $destinationFolder $folderName              

        New-Item -ItemType Directory $extractPath  
        Write-Host "Extracting $zip to $extractPath `r`n"                    
        [io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory([string]$zip.FullName, "$extractPath")        
    }           
}
```

When it reaches the `::ExtractToDirectory` line it throws an exception

```
Hit Line breakpoint on 'D:\MyDeploymentScript.ps1:85'
[DBG]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>> 
Exception calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Could not find a part of the path 
'Z:\Build_11_17_13_28\Web'."
At D:\MyDeploymentScript.ps1:85 char:9
+         [io.compression.zipfile]::ExtractToDirectory([string]$zip.FullName, "$ex ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryNotFoundException
```

But the crazy thing is if I breakpoint that same spot and check the path with `Test-Path` it returns True. I am at a loss for what can be wrong right now.

```
[DBG]: PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>> Test-Path Z:\Build_11_17_13_28\Web
True
```

Comment: When you map the `Z:` drive are you using `New-PSDrive`? If so, are you using `-Persist`? If not, then the .net method you're calling probably can't see the drive.

Comment: Test-path only determines if a path exists, it doesn't verify that it is a directory. Is Z:\Build_11_17_13_28\Web in fact a directory? Does your script have write permission to the directory? You could also examine $error[0].exception to see if the InnerException member exists and has a value.

Comment: @briantist Good catch adding that worked. Strange that during Debug I can still navigate to Z: even though persist was not enabled.

Comment: @tyh I've added an answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you might be mapping your drive in the earlier portion of the script with [`New-PSDrive`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx). The drive created with that cmdlet is only visible within PowerShell, unless you use the `-Persist` switch. That switch creates it as an actual mapped drive (as though you had used `net use` or group policy or mapped it through explorer).

The `.ExtractToDirectory` method you're calling can't see any of the powershell provider namespaces, so it needs a real mapped drive or UNC path that's visible to the whole operating system.

Remember that if you're using `-Persist` you may also want to unmap the drive manually now.